# About Spatial ETL and how much is it used in the GIS industry

Tags: software-recommendations, references, industry

Because I've been noticing that some internships are requesting some know-how of this tool.

I would like to ask how is it used in the industry?
What do you use it for at your job?
Where could you learn it?

as far as I know my Geomatics program doesn't offer courses in any related SpatialETL software.

Comment: I think this is a valid and good question - it would be well suited to the community-wiki format.

Comment: Although interesting I think this question is unsuitable for our focussed Q&A format due to being too broad (several questions included) and too likely to generate opinions. You could try clicking **tags** here to get an idea of how much the community is using it and [tag:fme] to see how they are using it.

Comment: Perhaps the question could be rephrased to say something like "How do you use FME in your role?" - it's still more of a wiki question, but it's specific.

Comment: quite easy to learn. I have edited and voted to reopen. Then I will change this comment to an answer. lots of free online virtual classrooms http://www.safe.com/learning/training/  for desktop. many resources here... http://playground.fmeserver.com/demos/ to use server

Comment: Here's a presentation I did on how we use FME at the FME world tour last year: http://www.slideshare.net/SafeSoftware/building-the-spatial-enterprise-of-denver-public-schools

Comment: For those who are unaware of Community Wiki and when to use or not use it, please see http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/550/flagging-as-community-wiki.  In its edited form there are still three (rather than one) questions, but each of those has potential to attract dozens of answers of varying quality and I think it is far more useful when there are no more than a handful (preferably just 2-3) to choose from when someone "just wants to get an answer" as they search our site.

Comment: I get the feeling it's an issue because it's a specific software. If you changed "FME" in the title to "Spatial ETL" then I guess it would be more acceptable.

Comment: Agree with Mark re-opened with community wiki

Comment: @MarkIreland Spatial ETL is broader than FME so to me that change makes the question less rather than more suitable for our focussed Q&A format.  After nearly a year with no answers I am going to go with my original feeling that this question is far too broad for our focused Q&A format.